# Django Tastypie: Allow Random as an Order By Option

Tags: django, tastypie

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921284/return-random-items-with-django-and-tastypie), I know how to randomly order a queryset in the Meta class of a tastypie Resource, but is there a way to make it an [available `order_by` option](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#ordering) instead of making it the default? It looks like anything defined in the `ordering` Meta setting must also be listed in the `fields` setting and ? obviously isn't a field. Without that I simply get,

```
{"error": "No matching '?' field for ordering on."}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the [`apply_sorting`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/bd75a923501d067c6fe881727e61439e86772fb6/tastypie/resources.py#L1955) method [(documentation)](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id6) on your `Resource`, maybe something like this (untested):

```
class YourResource(ModelResource):
    def apply_sorting(self, obj_list, options=None):
        if options and '?' in options.get('order_by', ''):
            return obj_list.order_by('?')
        return super(YourResource, self).apply_sorting(obj_list, options)
```

You might need to copy code [from the `ModelResource` implementation](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/bd75a923501d067c6fe881727e61439e86772fb6/tastypie/resources.py#L1980) for getting the correct `order_by` value if this doesn't work as-is.

Comment: Thanks. I knew there had to be a method for overriding ordering like there is for modifying the filtering but I looked right past it.